# Question on the twisted cubic

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, projective-geometry

Suppose we are working over a field $k = \overline{k}$. How do I see that the map $$\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^3$$given by$$[a, b] \mapsto [a^3, a^2b, ab^2, b^3]$$gives an isomorphism of $\mathbb{P}^1$ with the variety in $\mathbb{P}^3$ cut out by $wz = xy$, $wy = x^2$, $xz = y^2$?

Comment: Step 1: Show that all the points $[x:y:z:w]=[a^3:a^2b:ab^2:b^3]$ satisfy those equations. Step 2: Show that any point $[x:y:z:w]$ satisfying those equations is of the form $[a^3:a^2b:ab^2:b^3]$.

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't work. Looks like the ordering of the coordinates is something else. Gimme a moment.

Comment: Try  $[w:x:y:z]=[a^3:a^2b:ab^2:b^3]$ instead